# how to smooth out css parallel circle spinning animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

https://jsfiddle.net/7rzny4ms/1/

It seems to stop for second when it does a full loop. I read that the stroke-dashoffset should be the circumference or greater but it still has that delay.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g>
    <circle class="progress" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" />
  </g>
</svg>

.progress {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 65;
  animation: progress-indef 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes progress-indef {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 251; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation looks pretty good and is correctly executed.

If clunky on some device/browser combination, it's not because it's not well thought out, but because you're animating `stroke-dashoffset`.

I would switch to animating `transform`, which is less resource intensive:

```css
.progress {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 65;
  animation: progress-indef 2s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 250.92135620117188;
}

@keyframes progress-indef {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g>
    <circle class="progress" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Note:** I changed `stroke-dashoffset` to `250.92135620117188` because that's the returned length (but I don't think that difference was causing the problem):

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.progress').getTotalLength())
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case, I would suggest to use only css to achieve what you need. Using border and animation, you can reach the same result.

The css

```
.loader {
   animation: loader-rotate 2s infinite linear;
   border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 5px solid #000;
   border-top: 5px solid transparent;
   border-right: 5px solid #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   transform: translateZ(0);
   width: 100px;
}

@keyframes loader-rotate {
   0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class='loader'></div>
```

Check it working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/italoborges/xqn4wb12/9/).